# Star-rating with css

Tags: html, css

so I have these radio buttons that form a star-rating component in reactjs, when I hover over the stars they paint in yellow but when I click in one of them and hover out of the stars the color doesn't stay and the gray color come back in all of them.

Here is the js file:

```
    render(){
    return (
      <div className="star-rating">
        <input id="star-5" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-5"></input>
        <label for="star-5" title="5 stars">
            <i className="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </label>
        <input id="star-4" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-4"></input>
        <label for="star-4" title="4 stars">
            <i className="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </label>
        <input id="star-3" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-3"></input>
        <label for="star-3" title="3 stars">
            <i className="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </label>
        <input id="star-2" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-2"></input>
        <label for="star-2" title="2 stars">
            <i className="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </label>
        <input id="star-1" type="radio" name="rating" value="star-1"></input>
        <label for="star-1" title="1 star">
            <i className="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
}
```

and the css:

```css
.star-rating {
    direction: rtl;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px
}

.star-rating input[type=radio] {
    display: none
}

.star-rating label {
    color: #bbb;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.star-rating label:hover,
.star-rating label:hover ~ label,
.star-rating input[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
    color: #f2b600
}
```

Any help?

Comment: could you share a working code snippet ?

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with React

Answer (score 2):

try this from [James Barnett](https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh)

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}

/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

```html
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It happens exactly the same, only in halves. :(

Comment: use dev tools to see the problem